# Why are the Lefty gang not supposed to talk about Florida?

Tags: dialogue, donnie-brasco

In *Donnie Brasco* (1997), the Lefty gang came back to New York by plane and gathered together to discuss their illegal business, i.e. shakedowns and hijackings:

> Sonny Black: What do you got, Nicky?
>
> Nicky: I got a guy boosted 30 tickets to Chaka Khan at the Garden.
>
> Sonny Black: What about Florida?
>
> Nicky: I thought **we weren't supposed to talk about Florida**.

Why aren't they supposed to talk about Florida?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Florida was a complete failure for the gang. It was supposed to bring them massive profits and increase their status in the organization, instead it was a bust and a complete embarrassment.